# Django datadump and loaddata not working due to fixture error

Tags: django, loaddata

Here is how I tried to dump mysql DB:

```
 python3 manage.py dumpdata > dumpdata.json
```

Then, I tried to reload it:

```
python3 manage.py loaddata dumpdata.json
```

This is the error that I get:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 226398200 (char 226398199)

django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/home/dumpdata.json':
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual case is when you print something during your application boostrap.
Those things you print will eventually end up in your `fixture.json`, messing up your JSON Structure.

To make things more readable, you can use:

`python3 manage.py dumpdata --indent 4 --natural-primary --natural-foreign -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission -e sessions  > dumpdata.json`

Some details:

- `--indent 4` will "pretify" your JSON output, it'll be way easier to checkup your Data
- `-e sessions` will remove `session`'s app data. Same for `contenttype` which often mess things up, `admin` and `auth.Permission`
- `--natural-primary --natural-foreign` will use some more natural PKs instead of IDs (eg when you have some `unique=True` fields)